# Getting "no internet" while using Reactjs to source an image

Tags: reactjs

I am getting a message "no internet" meaning my image has an error but I don't know how to rectify it. The code is as shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Footer.css'
function Footer(props) {
    return (
        <div className='footer-container'>
            <div className='footer-parent'>
               <img src={require('../../../assets/Home/shape-bg.png').default} alt='no internet connection'/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Footer;
```

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: I am new to reactjs will you mind guiding me, please how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how to display images in React:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Footer.css'
function Footer(props) {
return (
    <div className='footer-container'>
        <div className='footer-parent'>
           <img src={require('../../../assets/Home/shape-bg.png')} alt='no internet connection'/>
        </div>
        
    </div>
);
}

export default Footer;
```

I don't get your ".default".. Or just do it that way:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Footer.css'
import image from '../../../assets/Home/shape-bg.png'
function Footer(props) {
    return (
        <div className='footer-container'>
            <div className='footer-parent'>
               <img src={image} alt='no internet connection'/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Footer;
```

Here I just imported that image on top of that file and paste that image into `<image src />`.